# How can I convert a decimal to a Time in c#?

Tags: c#

In Excel I have a time value that is `1:35 PM`. When I change the cell format to general, the time value is shown as `0.565972222`.

In C# I need to convert the decimal representation (e.g. `0.565972222`)  to time (e.g. `1:35 PM`).

How can I do this?

I have tried using [`Convert.ToDateTime(0.565972222)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=net-7.0) but I can't convert it.

Comment: did you post a response ? it gone ?

Comment: How `0.565972222` is equivalent to 1:35PM ? How did you get that number?

Comment: its in excel and i changed the format of the cell to general

Comment: @Trish The description of the [TIME Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457) says that "... 12:00 PM is represented as 0.5 because it is half of a day ...". The decimal is the number of seconds divided by the total number of seconds in a day. 1:35 PM is 48900 seconds, the total number of seconds is 86400, and 48900 / 86400 = 0.565972222222222

Answer (score 2):

The value is the fraction of a day, so create a default DateTime and add the fraction as days to it:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime().AddDays(0.565972222);
```

Comment: Or `TimeSpan.FromDays(Double)`